# Can flags raised on this site be handled by Mods of other SE sites?

Tags: support, moderators, flagging, moderation

Sometimes I have observed that my chatroom flags are being handled by Mods from other SE sites.
Can the flags that I raise on posts on Hinduism.SE be similarly handled by other sites' moderators or by Community Managers?

If it's possible for them will they do it or still they won't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All ♦ moderators in the network moderate the chat.stackexchange.com server. This is indeed not limited to moderators of the site the chatroom belongs to, because chat often requires real-time moderation, not necessarily subject matter expertise, and moderators aren't online 24/7. On smaller sites like this, there are certainly days when none of the site's own moderators visit chat; sometimes, chat flags simply can't wait that long. There is no indication on the main site that there are pending flags in chat.

Flags raised on comments or posts on Hinduism.SE (and this Meta site) are only handled by Hindiusm's own moderator team. Community Managers *may* step in if the moderator team escalates an issue to them, or (in very rare cases) if all moderators are inactive and the community team is contacted in another way (e.g. the [Contact Us](/contact) form). ♦ moderators from other Stack Exchange sites (like me) can't handle those flags; our privileges here are limited to our reputation.